# What is the difference between scp and cp?

Tags: command-line, scp, cp

I'm really new to the command line and Ubuntu and I have recently learned that there is the `scp` command as well as the `cp` command. I tried to use an `scp` command to move a directory from Point A to Point B, but it didn't work. However, when I used `cp`, it worked just fine.

What is the difference between the two and how do I determine when to use one over the other?

Comment: Tried reading the manpage? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/scp.1.html and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/cp.1.html

Comment: What do you mean when you say it didn't work? scp can be used to copy files/directories from source to destination. Either source or destination or both can be local or remote.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**TL;DR** Read the man pages:

```
man scp
man cp
```

---

From `man scp`

```
NAME
     scp — secure copy (remote file copy program)

SYNOPSIS
     scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] [[user@]host1:]file1 ...
         [[user@]host2:]file2

DESCRIPTION
     scp copies files between hosts on a network.  It uses ssh(1) for data transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same security
     as ssh(1).  scp will ask for passwords or passphrases if they are needed for authentication.

     File names may contain a user and host specification to indicate that the file is to be copied to/from that host.  Local file names can be made
     explicit using absolute or relative pathnames to avoid scp treating file names containing ‘:’ as host specifiers.  Copies between two remote
     hosts are also permitted.
```

from `man cp`

```
NAME
       cp - copy files and directories

SYNOPSIS
       cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
       cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
       cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

DESCRIPTION
       Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
```

Comment: Well. I feel dumb. I totally forgot about the man pages. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

`scp` is really for remote copying over SSH. Eg:

```
scp /path/to/local/file user@server:/path/to/target/dir/
```

Answer (score 8):

`scp` or Secure Copy is primarily used to copy between a local host and remote host, or two remote hosts, via `ssh`

The `cp` command is for copying files locally, i.e. within your host's system.

The man pages that muru [has linked in comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645923/what-is-the-difference-between-scp-and-cp#comment926251_645923) should help you understand usage, but there are many tutorials on that internet thing too.

Answer (score 3):

You should also learn that there is a `man` command. Try it! `man cp`, `man scp`, `man man`.

`man cp` starts out:

```
    NAME
       cp - copy files and directories

SYNOPSIS
       cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
       cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
       cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

DESCRIPTION
       Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.
```

and `man scp` begins with:

```
    NAME
     scp — secure copy (remote file copy program)

SYNOPSIS
     scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2

DESCRIPTION
     scp copies files between hosts on a network.  It uses ssh(1) for data transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same security as     ssh(1).  Unlike rcp(1), scp will
     ask for passwords or passphrases if they are needed for authentication.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have spaces in filenames, scp handles them more nicely than cp, so I often use it even for copying on my local machine for that reason.